# How many different IPs are used in Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays

I use Tor since some months now and wonder how many different IPs are usable? I often check my IP and sometimes I see IP which i remember from some days before. 
But I found this site: http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ which shows that the possible number of IPs is nearly endless.
Are all the IPs listed on the page used in Tor or what is the meaning of it? For me it seems I can only use 50 or 100 different IPS

thanks for you help in advance :-)

Answer (score 7):

According to that website there is 1096 exit-nodes in the network.
The graphs on [Tor Metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html) seem to suggest a similar number, maybe ~1300.

Exit nodes are the relays that forward your traffic to whatever servers you're trying to talk to, so they're the ones that give you your IP address.
Therefore there's about 1096 or 1300 different IP addresses that you could end up with when you use Tor.

Answer (score 2):

Plus, about 80% of Tor traffic exits from just the top 50 nodes, so the likelyhood of seeing the same IP address is pretty high.

A lot of Tor nodes are just toys, with a trivial amount of bandwidth.  These feel-good relays get little if any traffic.

https://compass.torproject.org/#/by_country?exit_filter=all_relays&links&sort=cw&sort_reverse&country=&by_country=false&top=50&exits_only

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to answer this question by looking at the amount of Exit Nodes (the Tor Servers allowing exits). This statics are available for example on the [Tor Metrics page](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html?graph=relayflags&start=2014-07-20&end=2014-10-18&flag=Exit#relayflags) and [Compass](https://compass.torproject.org/#?exit_filter=all_relays&links&sort=cw&sort_reverse&country=&exits_only).